# How to view photos from all years on map?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, photos.app

In the iPhone Photos app, I am able to view a map with all of the photos from a given year when I am in the Photos/Years tab. Is it possible to do the same thing except with all photos, spanning all of the years? Or is a single year the highest level of aggregation that is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, year view is the highest level you can view a map for. With iOS 10, this is expanded to viewing all photos together on the map, but iOS 10 is not available yet at the time of writing.

Comment: Is this feature available in iOS 10? I can't seem to figure out how to access it.